# Setting up Frontend best practices for icons, webpack configs and unit testing in SAP Spartucus Storefront

Tags: user-interface, icons, karma-jasmine, angular8, spartacus-storefront

Could you please help me with my below questions:
1. How can I include a framework for handling icons (custom icons, icomoons, etc)
2. How can I use the unit testing framework to achieve specific code coverage and How to use protactor e2e testcases?
3. How can I modify the webpack settings (let say I want to divide one more chunk from vendor.js file)

Answer (score 0):

I believe answers to these questions aren't really spartacus-related.

1. Use it normally, as if you'd use them with any Angular app - [some Google answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/9bxa83/how_can_i_use_icomoons_local_icon_font_with/)
2. Use unit tests and e2e tests as usual - [unit testing docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing) and [protractor docs](https://protractortest.org)
3. [Webpack configuration docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)